# Database won't open after changing how Core Data initializes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

This is the current initialisation code in my app, based on cs193p by Paul Hegarty:

```
UIManagedDocument *database = nil;

if (!database) {
    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"stdDatabase"];
    database = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
    database.persistentStoreOptions = options;
}

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[database.fileURL path]]){
    [database saveToURL:database.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
        completionBlock(database);
    }];
} else if (database.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed){
    [database openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){
        completionBlock(database);
    }];
} else if (database.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) {
    completionBlock(database);
}
```

This is the new initialisation code I want to use, based on the "Core Data" book by Marcus Zarra:

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Corrida_de_Leitos" withExtension:@"momd"];
ZAssert(modelURL, @"Failed to find model URL");

NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
ZAssert(mom, @"Failed to initialize model");

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
ZAssert(psc, @"Failed to initialize persistent store coordinator");

NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
[moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];

[self setManagedObjectContext:moc];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSURL *storeURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        storeURL = [storeURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"stdDatabase"];

        NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [options setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
        [options setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [moc persistentStoreCoordinator];
        NSPersistentStore *store = [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error];
        if (!store) {
                NSLog(@"Error adding persistent store to coordinator %@\nUSERINFO:\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
        }

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self contextInitialized];
        });
});
```

This is the error I get when adding the store to the coordinator:

```
'Error adding persistent store to coordinator The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)
USERINFO:
{
    NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 14;
    NSUnderlyingException = "unable to open database file";
}'
```

How do I fix the new code so it is able to open the old database file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIManagedDocument will have created this sqlite file inside the UIManagedDocument package (a directory) so you need to get the URL to the original sqlite file and use this as the URL in the new version of the app, if necessary use the NSFileManager to move the file to another location, but that's not really necessary.  See example directory structure from UIManagedDocument, one for local and one for iCloud synced store. If its not iOS7 then check because the structure/names may be different.

In theory you can get the actual store file name from `UIManagedDocument.persistentStoreName` and simply append that to `UIManagedDocument.fileURL` - but in practice this omits the `StoreContent` subdirectory I think.

Usually `UIManagedDocument` would have created the file at `"stdDatabase/StoreContent/persistentStore"`.  But to be sure run the original version of the app in the simulator and then check exactly what path is used to create the store file.

The actual sqlite file should work fine as long as you open using the same options.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Checked the folder in the new version, checked in the previous versions, corrected the URL for the store and it opened. Thanks mate.

Comment: Hey, did you just append StoreContent with your previous URL? It is not working for me...

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `UIManagedDocument` creates the stack for you and saves your database file with a format not compatible with a SQLite file, if you want to use a SQLite file you first have to migrate the store (file), the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` have a method called `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:` which can do this migration.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, but it seems that it was not a format problem, but a path problem.

Comment: The UIManagedDocument sqlite file is compatible with the standard Core Data stack.  UIManagedDocument just uses a package (directory) structure to put the sqlite file in so you can't access the file using the same fileULR that you used for UIManagedDocument.